# Choosing the correct Arduino to process UART data with BaudRate 460800

Tags: arduino, uart, baud-rate

I'd like you to help me to choose an Arduino for:

1. Process data comes from a sensor over serial por (UART), the baudrate of the comming data is 460800. Later I'll save this data.
2. At the same time, the Arduino needs to send information over serial port (UART) BUT using others pins, the data will be sent to another device.

What package of Arduino do I need as minimum for this purpose.

Thanks for your support,
Jaspher.

Answer (score 0):

Well, referring to [this thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=49560.0) it looks like you can go to almost 1 000 000 baud rate by using the Teensy, an Arduino like clone : http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/

Hope this helps.